# a,b = b,a why have wrong result in this way

Tags: python-3.x

```
l = [2,3,1,2,4,5]
l[0],l[l[0]] =l[l[0]],l[0]
print(l)

#wrong result



l = [2,3,1,2,4,5]
l[l[0]],l[0] =l[0],l[l[0]]
print(l)

#correct result
```

I'm crushed~

and second one
the result between

```
l[0],l[l[0]] =l[l[0]],l[0]
```

and

```
l[0] = l[l[0]]
l[l[0]] = l[0]
```

result is also different

Comment: What is the output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, let's leave aside the fact you probably shouldn't be doing anything this complex anyway :-)

The statement `(a, b) = (c, d)` assigns a tuple of *values* to a tuple of *variables,* and the values are calculated before *any* assignments are done.

However, the assignments to the variables are sequenced, with each variable being *calculated and assigned* in a distinct operation. So, examine the following code (using `b` in place of `a[something]` to hopefully make it clearer):

```
>>> a = [0, 1] ; b = 0 ; (b, a[b]) = (1, 99) ; print(a)
[0, 99]
```

You get `[0, 99]`, because the assignment of `1` to `b` happens *before* the assignment of `99` to `a[b]` and, more importantly, before working out which object is actually *referred* to by `a[b]`.

So the second assignment is to the `a[1 (= changed b)]` variable rather than the `a[0 (= original b)]` one, because `b` has already changed at that point.

You see the same effect if you revert to using a list element rather than `b`:

```
>>> a = [0, 1] ; (a[0], a[a[0]]) = (1, 99) ; print(a)
[1, 99]
```

The only difference there is that `a[0]` has also changed since that's the object you're using for the index, rather than `b`.

---

The reason why your:

```
l[0] = l[l[0]]
l[l[0]] = l[0]
```

snippet is not working is because that's not even *close* to being a swap. It's effectively:

```
a = b
b = a
```

which will end up with `a` and `b` *both* having the value originally in `b`. A more "swappy" version would be:

```
tmp = b
b = a
a = tmp
```

and this would also work for your variant using `a[a[0]]` since each of those three lines is guaranteed to be fully executed *before* the next one starts.

The bottom line is that, while tuple assignment is a very powerful feature of Python, it *does* have a few subtle edge cases that may cause grief. It's still worth using, assuming you steer clear of those cases.